# STO 2023 Event Campaign Progress

Tags: star-trek-online

The 2023 Event Campaign is now ongoing. There are a total of 5 events happening over the year, each requiring 14 days of progress. If for some reason, I was unable to get the 14 progress points necessary to complete one of the events, would I be able to make it up in another event? For example, if I missed 5 days in the second event, would I be able to make it up in another event? For this to be possible, would there have to be extra days available for each event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Event Campaign is made up of a total of 5 Events happening over the year.  Each event lasts for **21** days.  (N.B. There are more than 5 Events through the year, however only 5 of them count towards the Event Campaign.)

For the individual event rewards, you only need to complete 14 days of progress.  However, you are still able to continue earning Event Campaign progress after completing the Event — meaning you can earn 21 days of Event Campaign progress per Event.  So, yes; you can make up another 7 days each event.

*Furthermore*, the Event Reward lockout timer is actually **20** hours, not **24** hours.  Since you can earn Event Campaign progress every 20 hours, this means that with (rather obsessive) dedication, you could earn up to 25 progress points per 3-week Event — which would allow you to complete the Event Campaign in **3** events, instead of requiring all 5.

Comment: I _totally_ have enough time to complete my daily event progress _every 20 hours!!_ :D